# Oracle query help - JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have two tables. I need to fetch data from one table and insert it into the other table, provided the data (say ID) does not exist in the second table. If the data exists, I need to update the values in the table for that id.

How can we achieve that?

I first collect all data from the first table in an arraylist, and iterate through the list. If the element presents in the second table, I call the update query. If not, I call the insert query.

Any other way to achieve this? I think it takes so much time, even though its straightforward.

PS: I dont have my query with me now

Comment: If both tables are same, you can truncate all the rows in 2nd table and run a single insert query from 1st table.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the MERGE statement. This is what you are looking for: `MERGE WHEN EXISTS THEN UPDATE NOT EXISTS THEN INSERT` (This is not the syntax)